# Can Global Disasters caused by Bearers (People with Terrible Luck) be Properly Contained?

Tags: science-based, society, humans, law

### The Bearer: Background

---

On Alternate Earth, studies and cases have shown that a *small percentage of the population (10%) is responsible for 90% of the bad luck*.

**These people are targeted by bad luck**, almost by cosmic forces: they are struck by lightning out of a sunny day, hit by cars whose brakes give out, and slip on banana peels in a no-eating zone.

Perhaps the luck is equalized somehow, because these people generally survive or are compensated for the situation.

The general populace once labelled these people as 'clumsy airheads', but following some high profile cases, they have since come to be known as **'Bearers'**, generally ranked class-F through class-A, each about 10x rarer and with worse luck than the next.

**Most of the time, disasters from Bearers do little harm to others**, and class-F through class-B have relatively tame bad luck, ranging respectively from the frequent stubbing of toes and slipping on bananas, to occasional injury and minor destruction of property.

Class-A bearers have a grade of bad luck involving weekly escapes from death, ranging from car crashes, apartment fires, and lightning strikes.

However, at a level 100x rarer and deadlier than class A, Class S Bearers are very rare, sitting at 1/100,000,000 people **but are disproportionately represented in history**: The Explosion of Black Tom Island (1875), the gunpowder explosion of Abbeville (1773), multiple unstoppable wildfires, the 1987 Stock Market Crash, and a [failed rocket launch that killed a cow in Cuba](http://www.digitaljournal.com/tech-and-science/science/herd-shot-around-the-world-the-last-east-coast-polar-launch/article/567614) (1986), to name a few.

Eventually, the world came to know about the potential disasters that could be wreaked by a single bearer in recent times, in Robert's Case (Misc section). After being hit by multiple tsunamis, hurricanes, and other natural disasters caused by one Bearer, the governments decided to change their stance on bearers, to prevent similar tragedies.

### Summary: Bearer Information

---

[image: Tetroid vs Earthquakes in Damage]

- A Bearer's bad luck is related to the recently discovered *Tetroid Waves*
- **The Bad Luck rating can be measured from Tetroid waves**
- E is 10x more bad luck (Tetroids) than F, D is 10x stronger than E, and so on.
- The Tetroid rating from F to S can be equated to local earthquakes (diagram above)
- All humans emit tetroids, Bearers are simply humans with more Tetroids
- It is easy to track Bearers, especially B to S-class, but Tetroid waves can be blocked by some common metals
- Blocking Tetroid waves does not prevent disasters, but does impact interference (see below)*
- The strength of Tetroid waves emitted prior correspond to the bad luck event that will ensue
- Luck seems to follow laws of conservation; an event of bad luck is equalized by almost equal good luck eventually
- A Bearer can emit Tetroids above their class when in distress, and generally the event triggered aims to solve the Bearer's problems
- Tetroid wave interference happens when two or more Bearers are nearby
- **Paradoxically, destructive interference (cancellation of bad luck) happens when multiple Bearers share similar harmonious emotional states**
- Conversely, constructive interference (amplification of bad luck) happens when multiple Bearers are emotionally chaotic

### Question

---

How should the World interact with Bearers, knowing that their numbers are steadily increasing, to best mitigate global and local disasters?

The best answer would also be *humane, properly integrate modern society with the Bearers, and prevent unwarranted discrimination where possible*.

Also, out of interest, who is responsible for the compensation, in the even of an accident? Will insurance rates for Bearers be disproportionately high, or will a common fund exist to support them?

Note: This happens on Alternate Earth, in reality we unfortunately cannot blame stubbed toes on Tetroid waves.

### Misc: Robert's Case

---

The following case is for background and humor, does not provide too much for question details:

> Up until a certain historically significant case, Bearers were not well-quantified or tracked. Domestic Class-S Bearers were not well-monitored or mitigated, and many remained unknown.
>  
>   This all changed after a case dealing with Robert 'Bob' Murphy, a seemingly ordinary, if not bad, conductor, who, unknown at the time, was also an S-class Bearer. After a failed concert, the depressed Bob was further implicated by an issue with pyrotechnics, which resulted in multiple casualties and many injuries. Following which Bob was framed by a Syndicate organization, and, charged with multiple murders, sentenced to the electric chair.
>  
>   As it turns out, Bob was certainly a bad orchestra conductor, but a good conductor in general; on the hour of his scheduled execution, a critical lightning storm erupted and struck the facility and multiple backup power plants, during which Bob escaped electrocution at the chair for electrocution from the sky. Seizing the chaos, Bob escaped the facility.
>  
>   All following attempts to capture Bob were primarily successful, but no results at containment or execution worked: prison vehicles carrying Bob would get flat tires or get into uncanny accidents. Eventually the government gave up and decided to just exile Bob into the ocean with some supplies and a fishing boat, hoping he'd maybe drift onto the shores of their rival country. **This was their worst idea yet.**
>  
>   Bob had the bad luck to end up in several tsunamis and hurricanes across the world, causing immense damage to multiple countries, before the United Nations, after an intense investigation, unanimously agreed to compensate him and exonerate him of the crimes he did not commit. To this day, Robert Murphy lives somewhere on an undisclosed island in the Bermuda Triangle.
>  
>  Since then, governments around the world have changed their stance and system on the treatment of Bearers, hoping to prevent a similar tragedy.

Comment: +1 just to celebrate a well-formed, readable, and detailed question. Cheers.

Comment: @JBH Thanks! I have trouble with keeping my wording concise at times, so I appreciate your positive feedback :).

Comment: One use for Bearers under S class might be product testing. l remember a short story where they put these "accident-prone" people in a lunar colony and sent them products to be tested. If the products survived the testing (and the testers survived the products) then the products passed.

Comment: @NomadMaker ah yes, literal murphy’s law testing, good idea :)

Comment: Many people in history (sailors in particular) really did believe that certain people brought bad luck and had to be driven away (or worse). https://timesmachine.nytimes.com/timesmachine/1885/03/06/102957718.pdf

Comment: @user3153372 ah yes, the seaman’s supersititions. Also, in history, the evil eye

Comment: How about intense monitoring? Bob is allowed to sell meat, but any of his customers who get so much as a sniffle get a cotton swab up their nose, and there's also ten seismometers within a hundred kilometres of him.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm well... I’m not sure if tetroid waves are infectious at this point, but monitoring around the clock of tetroid waves on Bob would certainly help

Comment: @Enthus3d in the first part I was referring to coronavirus jumping from animals to humans - one single, extremely unfortunate event. The second part, seismographs, was for detecting earthquakes or tsunamis caused by the Bearer.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm ah, I see. That makes sense xD

Comment: Define bad luck equalled with good luck. For example if the $ compensation from insurance is equalization or someone else just won't get hit by a car? What if Einstein is the Bearer and Charles Manson is the one who get rewarded with not getting smashed by falling piano?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Not the $ equalized, and it is just an observation made, that generally, the misfortune ultimately suffered by the bearer is relatively equal to the fortune. It is impossible to easily quantify, as a result.

Comment: Is there a way that the "common metals" could be used to mitigate constructive (amplified) interference but then suppressed when in a scenario where destructive (cancellation) interference  is in effect? I am imagining buddy system with taking a common metal out of a "faraday cage" of sorts to suppress a super luck event. Or is it a constant proximity effect?

Comment: @ITAlex good point, let me clarify that metal does not have a suppressive effect on the waves, just blocks them, so yes, barriers could potentially be constructed, eg in living spaces or communities, which can be raised in the event of excessively constructive interference as a safety measure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Two Roads:***

There are two directions your society can take with regards to bearers, and it somewhat depends on how the actual "ability" functions. The tetroid wave situation is complex, and I think only you fully understand it. Both of these solutions can be applied, or can be exclusive. It's up to you.

1. **Exile**: If the ability doesn't effect disasters outside the bearers, find a geologically stable place isolated from the bulk of humanity and offer a sliding scale of requirements and incentives to these folks to go there. S-scale people might be required to go there but offered vast sums of money in compensation for their troubles, in the same way a typhoid carrier might be required to isolate from those who are at risk. Those with the mildest cases will have no requirement, but will be offered lucrative jobs and compensations to go there. This will be a shifting solution, as asteroids crash there, aliens show up, and hurricanes materialize out of no where to lash (for example) the Aleutian Islands or Siberia. Concentrating these folks may magnify the effect (additive), or bad luck/good luck might cancel itself out and these folks will balance. If there is a hereditary element to this, there is a risk in concentrating this much potential into one breeding population.
2. **Control**: If there is a net total of good and bad luck in the world, and these people just concentrate it, then use them as a guide for these forces. Hurricanes will track towards them, so shift weather patterns to end droughts or avoid direct impacts on major cities. In a real crisis, an S-class talent can probably avert a nuclear attack because the bomb will fizzle out. Nations can pay into an international fund and buy, sell, and trade bad luck in the form of residence for these folks. Cuba gets hit with hurricanes all the time, so why not get paid to sponsor people, then make your nation hurricane-proof?

Comment: Good answer! I especially like the prospects of guiding disasters using the help of the Bearers. I can clarify the wave interference to be simpler on the question though. it’s just a matter of when Bearers are experiencing similar emotions, they cancel out each other’s bad luck

Comment: @Enthus3d So we want a dating app to match up people with this, so they come in synch and cancel the bad luck?  Major government grants for the world's best relationship experts to get comparable talent people to neutralize?

Comment: Potentially, essentially the waves are cancelled out by groups of them sharing similar emotions

Comment: @Enthus3d "Your mission, should you choose to accept it. Save Brent and Nancy's marriage. The fate of the world depends on it!" ;)

Comment: With what facilities? @DWKraus you are our social architect, please propose a solution! Look, this is not good, those two S-classes are... are... squabbling!! **Sound the Tornado and Hurricane alarms! Hurricane Brent and Nancy incoming! Get the people into shelters!**

Comment: I can't imagine what would happen if two S-Classes were matched together... all would be good when they're together, but what happens to the world when they break up? Would they need 20 A-classes on standby at all times? What alternate world have I created?!

Comment: @Enthus3d A world filled with drama. And yes, you would need to pair S-classes together, or carefully constructed communities/cults. Special intervention teams with combat/relationship therapists. SWEET!

Comment: News: Marriage Counselor Wins Nobel Peace Prize!

Comment: @DWKraus would you be able to add some aspect of this cultural/community/romance pairing to your answer, perhaps as a third option? Seems fleshed out enough to be a good option :)

Comment: I can see a metorite coming to fall on Bearers island. The good luck is that it will wipe all humanity but red pandas will survive.

Comment: Don't think many other answers will be coming. Will accept this as the canonical answer, for now, as it satisfies the best answer criteria the best. Think this could be improved as an answer, as it's missing the potential interactions with constructive/destructive waves/ coexistence.

Answer (score 16):

#### Vigilantism, Genocide & Eugenics

I'm sorry to basically go full Nazi on the first answer here.

History shows us what happens when we scapegoat a particular group of people as being responsible for all the suffering in the world. Replace ["The Eternal Jew"](https://encyclopedia.ushmm.org/content/en/article/nazi-propaganda)-style propaganda with "Here is this scientific proof that this group of people are making your life worse". You've basically got a "just add water" holocaust ready-to-go, without the need for a propaganda ministry.

They will be:

- The subject of vigilante attacks. If your existence was somehow causing hundreds of deaths, most moderate people would want to exile you to stop the damage, but some nut will want to kill you. That nutcase may have access to weapons and a Thetan (sorry - Tetroid) detector.
- In some countries they will be exiled away from population centres, "Ghettos" but further away.
- Some countries will class them as terrorists as put them to death.
- Eventually this will become some form of democide - either hidden (eg CIA assassination sort of things), or more like "Final Solution" level horrors, as the Ghettos are silently "dealt with".
- Researchers will try to detect what gene influences this condition. Pregnant mothers will have their babies screened for it and termination "requested".

Comment: I don’t like the implications of this answer very much, it makes me sad XD. But +1 for considering how the Bearers may end up as the next Pariahs

Comment: I figured that once the nature of the talent was understood, bias was inevitable. The talent will disrupt efforts to harm these folks, so as in the example in the question, bias will hurt the discriminators as much as the discriminated.

Comment: People are smart, humanity is stupid. We (as a crowd) will distill the message to its most basic meaning of "bearers bad, get rid of bearers". It will take significant isolation from the rest of the population and time and research effort (including the type done by doctor Mengele) to change to the "what you don't see, you don't think about" and pave the way to selective use of bearers in the larger society. And even then they will still be targets for crusades and social outcasts.

Comment: How about preventative detention, like with some people with mental illness or [Mary Mallon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Mallon)?

Comment: Good answer considering the natural human response, but cannot accept this as best answer, as this does not fit the best answer criteria outlined (humane and integration), neither does it offer any solutions to mitigate disasters, other than exploring gene changes, and attempting to assassinate Bearers (which will, from the question assumptions, potentially cause even more disasters due to increasing Bearer stress).

Answer (score 3):

## What about The Fortunate?

The fortunate would be the opposite end of the spectrum-the people for whom bad luck simply doesn't happen. They are the ones who could build a rocket out of a tin can and successfully circumnavigate the moon down to your simply lucky people who play a good stock market game or enjoy perfect health. They can be paired with the Bearers in areas or missions, so that the catastrophes that are waiting to happen will have generally fortunate results. So your car crash will unite two old lovers, or the hurricane will lead to policy changes desperately needed for decades, or a dropping of scientific papers will lead to the discovery of an unrealized theory. People who specialize in the measurement and classification of bearers would become popular (as mentioned in Enthus3d's comment in the thread) as they could generally mitigate the worst of the bearers. In this way, the bearers would create the chaos to make changes, and the fortunate would be used to change that negative chaos into a positive force for change.

Comment: Essentially, look for the Fortunates? Perhaps some of the Bearers are not Bearers, but Fortunates, and we've missed them this whole time, due to both operating based on Tetroids? Or perhaps, even more mind-numbing... Bearers and Fortunates are the same? +1 for opening up another train of thought in the answers :P

Comment: Awarded the bounty, for providing different answers/perspectives to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Enthus3d!

Answer (score 2):

### There is a certain amount of bad luck in the world; we need the Bearers, because otherwise we'd be suffering all that bad luck ourselves

Is it true?  Doesn't matter!  The most humane route for dealing with Bearers is propaganda on their behalf.  These aren't the bad guys, these are the martyrs.

In exactly the same way that a lightning rod protects your house by attracting any lightning away from the more vulnerable parts, Bearers attract the lightning of misfortune away from us regular folk.  At least, if they're used correctly.  Can we position them to make sure that tsunamis never hit  nuclear plants or populated coastal areas?  Can they keep the tornadoes away from schools and residential neighborhoods?

Sure, for the protection of regular people, S-Class Bearers cannot be allowed to go wherever they like, whenever they like, but competing institutes for probability research, and other governments and private entities, can try to find ways to make use of these living tetroid generators, be it research or an attempt to focus bad luck.  They may find themselves in high demand!  (What "luck".)

Don't be surprised, for that matter, if some governments even try to recruit such people into military or espionage roles.  Especially if tetroid radiation is difficult to detect, and public spaces cannot easily be made secure against incursion.

Obviously, if Bearers become living weapons, this is going to undermine the Bearer-Martyr propaganda, and you'll end up with a complex effect where many of the general public are unsure what to think.    But you can certainly start out with benevolent organizations casting Bearers as the people "taking one for the team", not just being the source of others' misfortune.

Comment: +1 for the bits about the propaganda; perhaps an image change could be made to let the Bearers be more bearable for the rest of the population :P